# 7.4v DC to 5v DC (with 1A and 2A options)

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I am trying to make a power bank out of the cells of a laptop battery. Each cells are 3.7V 2200mAh .I tried using a 7805 voltage regulator with the two cells in series, but the output current was not sufficient to charge the phone. The output it gave was about 480mA. I have also tried using a 5V zener diode but it got so hot that my breadboard was melted (i dont know if i did it wrong or used a zener diode of low wattage. So i wanted to ask how i could make a power bank of output and options of 5V 1A and 5V 2A.Please give me directions or links that could help me..

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3):

It's quite possible that the two series cells were discharged somewhat and together, instead of producing something like 7.4 volts in series, the voltage was below 7V. Once the voltage drops below 7V, a 7805 regulator will not work very effectively. You could try 3 in series but the 7805 could get hot due to it dropping maybe 5V in order to put 5V onto the load.

I would use switching buck-regulators for doing this job because they are more energy efficient and there is a three terminal regulator with exactly the same pin-out as a 7805 that will run much cooler and running it from 3 cells would be more effective. [Link](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CEcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.murata-ps.com%2Fdata%2Fmeters%2Fdms-78xxsr.pdf&ei=QsqVU6j-G-He7Aa824CADg&usg=AFQjCNF9SG4h9vNcKcJnUzvgDrwjdSQ_kA&bvm=bv.68445247,d.ZGU). You can also get a 2 amp version. From Farnell the stock number is 151-8685.

Comment: +1 Or use an LM1117T-5.0/NOPB LDO, $1.49 from Digikey. Must have an aluminum electrolytic or tantalum cap on the output for stability (if a ceramic cap is used, add 1 ohm resistor in series). Pinout is **not** the same as a 7805.

Comment: @Dzarda who are you commenting for - Spehro or me?

Comment: Sorry, just meant to emphasize the need to always check for pinouts.